# Android studio how to use SharedPrefences to store page activity?

Tags: android-studio, sharedpreferences

my question is i want to store activity page on sharedpreferences
For example:
1) User click button A to Main2Activity
2)Shared preference store Main2Activity
3)Restart application, Main page will become Main2Activity.

Here is my coding, it did not have any error, but it did not work anything.

Hope someone can explain and show me the solution

Thank you

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colour1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colour2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            storepage(Main2Activity.class);
            newpage();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            storepage(Main3Activity.class);
            thirdpage();

        }
    });
}

private void storepage(Class page) {
    //name means give the name of sharedpreference file
    //mode private means only this application can access shared preference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("changepage", MODE_PRIVATE);
    //create edit for shared preference file
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    //select the type of value need to inserted
    editor.getClass();
    //save the value
    editor.apply();
}

private Class<? extends SharedPreferences> getpage() {
    //name means give the name of sharedpreference file
    //mode private means only this application can access shared preference
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("changepage", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Class<? extends SharedPreferences> result = sharedPreferences.getClass();
    return result;

}
private void newpage()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
private void thirdpage()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Main3Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Comment: You dont need to store activity for this. You can save a boolean variable example: `isButtonClicked`. If the boolean is true open activity 2 else open activity 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store an activity in sharedpreferences. What I would do in this situation is to create a boolean variable like `isClicked` and set it to true when the button is clicked for the first time then store that variable to sharedpreferences. Then you could make a splashscreen which retrieves that boolean variable from sharedpreferences then checks if `isClicked` is true then open `Main2Activity` else open some other activity. [Here](https://medium.com/viithiisys/android-perfect-way-to-create-splash-screen-ca3c5bee137f) is a link to tutorial on how to create a splashscreen.

**SPLASHSCREEN CLASS**

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    checkBtnClicked();
 }

 private void checkBtnClicked() {
    boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREF", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isBtnClicked", false);

    if (isBtnClicked) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class));
        finish();

    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, //activity where button is));
        finish();
    }
 }
}
```

**ACTIVITY WHERE BUTTONS ARE**

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //store boolean to sharedpreferences
    }
});
```